# Divide total value of 128 in three rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql

Divide sum of quantity 128 in three rows in SQL Server. 
Making three rows like:

```
50
50
28
```

Comment: Where is your data structure?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Without knowing more it is difficult to see why `select 50 union all select 50 union all select 28` wouldn't be a good answer. We'd like to know (at least) how the code should know to use 50 as the upper limit and whether the solution needs to extend to other inputs. For example if you have input 170, do you want 50,50,50,20 or something else?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @SteveLovell Yes the output should be same like that if have 204 then it should be 
Row  Qty
 1        50
 2        50
 3        50
 4        50
 5         4
It should create 5 rows

Comment: Okay, my code below would handle that just by changing 128 to 204. Is this data from a table you wish to split into separate rows based on the value in a field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you have yet to clarify your needs, so I'm going out on a limb here. I offer this less as an answer and more as an encouragement to get you to clarify your question. The attached *might* be what you want ... but if not, which seems very likely, it should give you a better idea what you really need to ask:

```
WITH MySplit AS
(
    SELECT
        128 as CurrentValue,
        50 as MaxPartition

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CurrentValue - MaxPartition,
        MaxPartition
    FROM
        MySplit
    WHERE
        CurrentValue - MaxPartition > 0
)

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN MaxPartition < CurrentValue then MaxPartition
        ELSE CurrentValue
    END AS Partitition
FROM
    MySplit
```

### Alternative:

Assuming you have your value 128 (or something else) in a table somewhere, and you want to split the row containing 128 into three rows containing 50, 50 and 28 (and generally partitions of 50 plus a remainder in the last one):

```
DECLARE @rows_to_split AS TABLE (my_number INT)
INSERT INTO @rows_to_split VALUES (128),(204),(96)

--Everyone should have a "numbers" table, you may need additional rows.
--Search SO for how to generate them efficiently.
DECLARE @numbers AS TABLE (num int)
INSERT INTO @numbers VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

SELECT
    r.my_number,
    n.num,
    CASE WHEN n.num* 50 > r.my_number THEN (r.my_number - (n.num-1)*50) ELSE 50 END AS split
FROM
    @rows_to_split r
    JOIN @numbers n ON
        (n.num-1)*50 < r.my_number
ORDER BY
    r.my_number,
    n.num
```

Comment: Not sure whether this was any help to you Syed. If it was, then please mark my answer as accepted. If not, please clarify your requirements and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: That helped me and that is what i was looking Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. I also just added an alternative which you might find useful. If you  could mark my answer as accepted by way of a thank you, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

---- I have done it in another way look my code.If suppose I have Two Digits to splits.Can we do it without using loops

DECLARE @COUNT INT;
DECLARE @ITEMCOUNT INT;

```
DECLARE @ShipTable table(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
WbDItemNo char(15),
Qty int 


)
INSERT INTO @ShipTable
VALUES
(
'TEST ITEM',
59

),('TEST ITEM 1',225)

SELECT * FROM @ShipTable

SET @COUNT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ShipTable)
DECLARE @TOTALQTY INT 
DECLARE @UPAMOUNT INT
DECLARE @DIVISIONALVAL INT
DECLARE @DIVIDEBY INT
DECLARE @ITEM VARCHAR(50)
SET @DIVIDEBY=50;


DECLARE @ITEMNO VARCHAR(50)
WHILE(@COUNT>0)
BEGIN

  SET @TOTALQTY=(SELECT Qty FROM @ShipTable WHERE ID=@COUNT)
  SET @ITEM=(SELECT WbDItemNo FROM @ShipTable WHERE ID=@COUNT)


  SET @UPAMOUNT=@TOTALQTY%@DIVIDEBY
  SELECT @ITEM,@UPAMOUNT
  SET @DIVISIONALVAL=@TOTALQTY/@DIVIDEBY
  SET @DIVISIONALVAL=FLOOR(@DIVISIONALVAL)

  WHILE(@DIVISIONALVAL>0)
  BEGIN 
  SELECT @ITEM,@DIVIDEBY
  SET @DIVISIONALVAL=@DIVISIONALVAL-1
  END


  SET @COUNT=@COUNT-1
END
```